# Getting Segmentation fault when using pow, XOR or pointer in C

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

Can anyone please explain what's wrong? am just getting Segmentation fault. am using "gcc code.c -o code -lm" to compile it.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int unsint;
const char* secret="E...EA...WSC..OP.S.EE.SSA.C....A";

void funca(unsint* a, unsint b) {*a^=b;}

int main() {   
        unsint *a = 0;
        for (int counter=0;counter<=31;counter++) {
                char charec=secret[counter];  
                long lnum=counter==0?1:pow(2,counter);
                charec==46?funca(a,lnum):NULL;
        }
        printf("\nresult: %u\n",a);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: "T...EX...T.M.E.SS.A.G.EE.." has 26 chars. Your counter goes up to 31.

Comment: How long is `secret`? And how many elements you are trying to index in the loop?

Comment: Well for starters, `secret` has 26 characters in it, but you iterate through 31.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `secret` is defined above, and is surprisingly ... too short.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It was a rhetorical question :) To trigger the thinking process.

Comment: also `pow(2,counter)` is a float. You should multiply-accumulate by 2 or lshift in your loop so you get the integer computation for free.

Comment: `long lnum=counter==0?1:pow(2,counter);` ==> `long lnum = 1 << counter;`

Comment: And don't abuse the ternary operator.

Comment: sorry secret variable should be "D....E.AD.B...E.E.F....F!.X..2.."

Comment: [cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/XNfAyU)

Comment: If you declared the `secret` text as an array, you could use `sizeof(secret) - 1` instead of the constant 3` in you `for` loop.

Comment: This statement is bothering me: `charec==46?funca(a,lnum):NULL;`.  Your code would be much clearer if you used `if (charec == '.') {funca(a,lnum);}`.

Comment: Your code may be more efficient if you used `(1 << counter)` instead of `pow(2, counter)`.  Some compiler may optimize this at higher optimization settings.

Comment: If you need to use `#define` to shorten types, take a keyboarding / typing class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a null pointer

```
unsint *a = 0;
```

and you never point `a` at anything, so when you dereference it, you crash.

You should also not throw floating point into the mix (`pow(2,0)` is 1, by the way, so you don't need a special case), and you shouldn't abuse the ternary operator or use non-portable ASCII codes when you can use portable character literals.

I suggest something like this:

```
int main() {
    unsigned int a = 0;
    for (unsigned int counter = 0; counter <= 31; counter++) {
        if (secret[counter] == '.') {
            a ^= 1 << counter;
        }
    }
    printf("\nresult: %u\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions  :D